# Why is my code returning nothing?

Tags: python, list

My code is suppose to take in a list of numbers, sort them, and then remove any duplicates. However, when using a debugger, it tells me that the object of NoneType has no length, implying that my function is returning nothing.

```
def makeUnique(numList):
    numList = numList.sort()
    i = 0
    while i < (len(numList)):
        if numList[i] == numList[i + 1]:
            del numList[i + 1]
        else:
            i = i + 1
        return numList

makeUnique([7,2,5,5,3,1,0])
```

I've gone through so many questions asking the same thing but it just doesn't seem to be working. This is majorly frustrating.

Comment: You are unconditionally returning from the function at the end of the first iteration; don't indent `return`.

Comment: For that matter, you are mutating the input list, which means there is no need to return it.

Comment: By the way, `sorted(set(some_list))` does the same thing OP intends to do.

Comment: In addition to the above you do not store, process or print the return value of your function call in any way.

Answer (score 4):

```
numList = numList.sort()
```

`sort()` sorts a list in place. It doesn't return anything; it modifies the original list. Make this either:

```
numList.sort()
```

or:

```
numList = sorted(numList)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem with numList=numList.sort(). numList.sort() returns null after sorting and you assigned that to list again means numList has becom None and further raising error when you are using it in len method

```
  def makeUnique(numList):
        numList.sort()
        i = 0
        while i < (len(numList)):
            if numList[i] == numList[i + 1]:
                del numList[i + 1]
            else:
                i = i + 1
            return numList

    print makeUnique([7,2,5,5,3,1,0])
```